# Responsive breakpoints not working for slick slider

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive, slick.js

I have implemented slick slider which works fine without resizing the browser. But when I resize the browser to 1024 then the responsive breakpoint settings doesn't work.

jQuery:

```
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  variableWidth: true,
  variableHeight: true,
  mobileFirst: true,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: false
    }
  }]
});
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/hn7xsa4y/4/

Comment: Use CSS3 media queries to respond your slider.

Comment: Does the slider break after you physically resize?  is it broken if you were to reload the page?  *DO NOT* worry about scripting for people who resize their browser.  It's a waste of time.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Slider doesn't break after I resize the browser. It works fine but that settings doesn't work. If I reload the page at that breakpoint then it works as well.

Comment: @Cage So you mean I need to adjust the width and height of the image for each media query?

Comment: @Cage Tried with media query and adjusted the image width with px and it worked...but have no clue why that setting is not working.

Answer (score 31):

Add this settings to your code;

```
$(".slides").slick({
    autoplay:true,
    mobileFirst:true,//add this one
}
```

Comment: Care to explain why exactly?

Comment: the reason it *may* work is because when you add `mobileFirst:true` it will use the 'base' settings first (in this case `slidesToShow: 1,`) - the 'base' settings being those NOT in the `responsive` array -

Comment: additionally, using `mobileFirst` makes it easier to think about - your `responsive` settings then contain the 'larger' sizes - in the example above its mobile first so it uses `slidesToShow=1` then at 1024 it uses `slidesToShow: 4,`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me.

```
    function resetSlick($slick_slider, settings) {
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                if ($(window).width() < 320) {
                    if ($slick_slider.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                        $slick_slider.slick('unslick');
                    }
                    return
                }

                if (!$slick_slider.hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
                    return $slick_slider.slick(settings);
                }
            });
        }

 slick_slider = $('.client-logos');
    settings = {
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        prevArrow: '',
        nextArrow: '',
        pauseOnHover: true,

        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
            // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
            // settings: "unslick"
            // instead of a settings object
        ]

    };
     slick_slider = $('.container');
    settings = {
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        prevArrow: '',
        nextArrow: '',
        pauseOnHover: true,

        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
            // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
            // settings: "unslick"
            // instead of a settings object
        ]

    };
    slick_slider.slick(settings);
    resetSlick(slick_slider, settings);
```

Add this to your js and call the slider as shown.

and in your css make the `slide` `display: inline-block;` that's it. will work on all responsive screens.

Answer (score 0):

Add `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` option in each breakpoint.

```
 {
  breakpoint: 786,
    settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              }
 },
 {
  breakpoint: 568,
    settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, "variableHeight" option does not exist in [Slick Carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

To solve your issue, remove `variableWidth: true`, because this will make your slides take full with of the carousel.
And you can also not use "mobileFirst" option if your page is not using this methodology.

So finally your config should be like this, below

```
$('.slider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  mobileFirst: true, //optional, to be used only if your page is mobile first
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      centerMode: false,
    }
  }]
});
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`mobileFirst:true,`//add this to your JavaScript file and it should work :)

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49350486/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30356620)

Comment: @EricAya my bad won't do it again :)

Answer (score 0):

*tl;dr* When multiple sliders on page changing `$('.selector').slick({...})` order helped

I had similar issue. I don't understand why but `slidesToShow: 2` didn't take effect on mobile device for me although if you resize it back and forth it took effect. `mobileFirst:true` helped but broke desktop. Adding both `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` didn't help. But when I placed initialization of sliders in the same order as they appear on the page it worked. I don't understand why... I don't understand how to fix this if there're multiple pages with different slider locations...

Answer (score -1):

First, you use old version of slick in your example. This verson doesn't support `mobileFirst` property.
Second, you must remove `variableWidth` if you want to use `slidesToShow` property.

Comment: On 1025 and above the slider will show one centered image with 2 partial images at left and right which works fine in my fiddle using variableWidth(otherwise I was getting blank white spaces). Now when I resize the browser to 1024 then it will show 4 slides (without cropping the images). I am using the latest version of slick.

Comment: Adjustments within the media query works for me but I was trying to find the reason why the breakpoints doesn't work as stated in the plugin page.

Comment: see my fiddle. On 1024 and below one centered slide, 1025 and above - 4 slides.

Comment: It would be the opposite. On 1024 - 4 slides and above -1 slide centered.

Comment: just to let everyone here know if you add "mobilefirst" option, it will ignore the desktop version and you will ended up having same setting for desktop