# Slick carousel ignoring responsive breakpoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am building a carousel using [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and I've got some responsive breakpoints set as seen here:

```
var slidesNumber = $('.aslide').length;
var options = {
  rows: (slidesNumber > 3 ? 2 : 1),
  slidesPerRow: 3,
  slidesToShow: (slidesNumber > 3 ? 1 : 3),
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: true,
  arrows: false,
  dotsClass: 'slick-dots slick-dots-black',
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1280,
      settings: {
        slidesPerRow: 2,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        rows: 2,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        slidesPerRow: 1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        rows: 1,
      }
    }
  ]
}

$('.slider').slick(options);
```

however, Slick ignores the 768px breakpoint completely and display 2 rows of 2 slides each instead of 1 row 1 slide. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/petarvasilev/652ou9nL/9/).

I've looked [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick/issues/2764631) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077979/responsive-breakpoints-not-working-for-slick-slider).

The `mobileFirst` setting makes Slick ignore even the 1280px breakpoint.

I've looked at other posts as well but found no solution yet.

EDIT 1:

Also, noticed in the JSFiddle, if you load the page with window width less than 768px it shows 3 slides in 2 rows but if you resize up and down it starts showing 2 slides in 2 rows again.

Comment: If you are just using JSFiddle for this I think it might throw off your breakpoints since the output section has <html> and <body> tags inside it, same as each of the 4 sections. It might calculating the screenwidth from them instead of the actual one.

Comment: I've got the problem on a real website. I just replicated the issue in JSFiddle.